# Detecting when a retry has occurred in a Asp.net MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, event-handling

I have an asp.net mvc application that authenticates calls into another service.  In the event of a timeout or hitting a rate limit I want to retry the call.  I found endjin's [retry framework](https://github.com/endjin/Endjin.Retry).  I implemented it in my code like this:

```
Retriable.Retry(() => Login());
```

And that works, it retries the event if an error is thrown.  I want to write to a log anytime a retry occurs with what the method being retried is and how many times we've tried.  It seems like there should be an event that fires when retry happens but I haven't been able to get a working event handler for it.

Am I going about this right?

Comment: The documentation seems rather scarce on that project, so you might want to post a new issue there. However, I noticed that there is an [`IRetryStrategy.PrepareToRetry`](https://github.com/endjin/Endjin.Retry/blob/master/Solutions/Endjin.Retry/Contracts/Retry/Strategies/IRetryStrategy.cs#L19) method that you could use if you build your own `IRetryStrategy` implementation.

Comment: That worked, thanks.